# Where does the summation convention break?

Tags: matrices, summation, convention

In my work I have spotted something "weird". Consider the matrix

\begin{align*}
  M_{ij} =1-\delta_{ij}.
\end{align*}
I want to find $ M^{2} $  in terms of its components. So
\begin{align*}
  (M^{2})_{ij} 
   =(M M)_{ij}& =M_{ia}M_{aj} \tag{1}\\ 
  & = (1-\delta_{ia})(1-\delta_{aj}) \tag{2}\\ 
  & =1+\delta_{ia}\delta_{aj}-\delta_{ia}-\delta_{aj} \tag{3}\\ 
  & =1+\delta_{ij}-1 -1 \tag{4}\\ 
  & =-1+\delta_{ij},\tag{5}
\end{align*}
however, this is clearly wrong, as consider $ n=2 $ , in which case we have
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} 0 &  1 \\
                  1 &0   
  \end{pmatrix} 
  \begin{pmatrix} 0 &  1 \\
                  1 &  0 
  \end{pmatrix} 
  =\begin{pmatrix} 1 &  0 \\
                  0 &  1 
  \end{pmatrix} 
  . 
\end{align*}
A guess where this goes wrong is from $ (1) $ to $ (2) $ as expanding $ (3) $ gives $ k $  as a free index, over which I have summed over. I did so because I couldn't leave it since it is a dummy variable. My best guess is that I am simply not allowed to go from $ (1) $  to $ (2) $  but I am not sure as to why that is.

If anybody could shine some light on this I would greatly appriciate it.

Comment: Is your matrix the matrix of ones except on the diagonal where it is zero?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $1$ in the definition is a matrix, not a number, and should be written as $1_{ij}$. ($J_{ij}$ would be better because the matrix of all ones doesn't act like the multiplicative identity, but I will leave it as $1_{ij}$.) Not writing the indices here causes problems later.

Following your derivation, we get
\begin{align*}
  M_{ij} =1_{ij}-\delta_{ij},
\end{align*}
and computing $M^2$, we get
\begin{align*}
  (M^{2})_{ij} 
   =(M M)_{ij}& =M_{ia}M_{aj} \tag{1}\\ 
  & = (1_{ia}-\delta_{ia})(1_{aj}-\delta_{aj}) \tag{2}\\ 
  & =1_{ia}1_{aj}+\delta_{ia}\delta_{aj}-\delta_{ia}1_{aj}-1_{ia}\delta_{aj} \tag{3}\\ 
  & =n 1_{ij}+\delta_{ij}-1_{ij} -1_{ij} \tag{4}\\ 
  & =(n-2) 1_{ij} +\delta_{ij},\tag{5}
\end{align*}
where we see the important error occurred in equation 4, where $1_{ia}1_{aj} = n 1_{ij} \neq 1_{ij}$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. A quick question on the summation convention: generally, can we always multiply terms, in other words, given two expressions each with say two free indecies $a$ and $b$, can we always multiply them out and apply the summation convention?

Comment: I don't understand your question fully. However, if each term has the proper number of indices (so you are never adding/subtracting terms with different indices), then the summation convention should work, as it would just be ignoring the same $\sum$s at the front of the expression.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. I wanted to ask you, are there any circumstances in which the summation convention breaks - that is- places where I should be avoiding using it?

Comment: I don't think I can answer that question verbally or fully - it might be better to ask that in a separate question. For a too-tight response, the summation convention is fine if (1) you only have sums and products, (2) each term doesn't use an index more than twice, (3) you don't add terms with different free indices, and (4) both sides of the equation have the same free indices. I believe you can extend (1) to allow linear transformations, but I am not sure of a more general answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the phenomenal answer.

Answer (score 1):

(1) is already wrong—the right-hand side should be $\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^n M_{ia}M_{aj}$, with a summation sign. This will eventually expand to
$$
\sum_{a=1}^n 1 - \sum_{a=1}^n \delta_{ia} - \sum_{a=1}^n \delta_{aj} + \sum_{a=1}^n \delta_{ia}\delta_{aj},
$$
from which you should be able to recover the correct answer. (In your method, you guessed to sum certain parts of the formula but not all of them; writing the sums explicitly takes the guesswork away.)

Comment: The summation sign can be nice to have as a learning tool, but it is often elided by convention. So insisting that should be there isn't quite right in my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur But omitting it when some of the symbols have no indices is bound to lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: @TedShifrin This is very true. If you want implicit summation, then each term needs to have free indices that match those of every other term in order to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(1-\delta_{ij})$, a matrix of order $n$. Then an easy calculation show that $A$ looks like a matrix which have all the entries with $1$ except when $i=j$ and it least case the matrix have only $0$ in the diagonal.

If you calculate $A^2$ you can notice that we always sum the $1$ by each entry except when we multiply the entry with $i=j$. Hence we always have in all the entries with $i=j$the sum of $n-1$ ones. Otherwise we always sum $1$ in all the entries except when $i=j$ twice (in the row and in the column of $A$), which give the sum of $n-2$ ones. As result, if $A$ is a matrix of order $n$ and $A$ is written as above.

$$A^2=(a_{ij})=\begin{cases}a_{ij}=n-1 \, \text{if i=j } \\ a_{ij}=n-2 \, \text{if $i\neq j$} \end{cases}.$$

Comment: Hi @Brien, thank you for the anwer. I know the answer, I want to understand why is what I have written wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems because if $A=(a_{ij})$ the matrix $A^2\neq (a_{ij})(a_{ij})$

Comment: You can find the general formula for the product of two matrix $A$ and $B$ here and apply the product rule correctly  where $A=A$ and $B=A$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication